# How to replace firebase notification with your own on Android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, android-broadcastreceiver

My Android application gets firebase notifications. And I need to localize this notifications depends on application language on the client side, not on server side.

If application is in foreground I use `onMessageReceived()` from `FirebaseMessagingService` and push my own localized notification. But if application is in background `onMessageReceived()` doesn't called.

In this case I use my own class extended `BroadcastReceiver`. `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method catches notification, I localize it and push. Everything goes good, but in the end I get 2 push notifications: my own localized and firebase.

How can I get rid of this firebase notification and get only my own?

```
public class FirebaseDataReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

Context context;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    this.context = context;
    Bundle dataBundle = intent.getExtras();
    String title = "";
    String body = "";
    String type = "";
    String objectId = "";

    if (dataBundle != null) {
        type = dataBundle.getString("type");
        objectId = dataBundle.getString("objectId");
        title = NotificationUtils.getNotificationTitle(context, dataBundle);
        body = NotificationUtils.getNotificationBody(context, dataBundle);
    }

    Intent newIntent = new Intent(context, TutorialActivity_.class);
    newIntent.putExtra("target", "notification");
    newIntent.putExtra("type", type);
    newIntent.putExtra("objectId", objectId);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
            0,
            newIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.splash_mini)
            .build();

    deleteLastNotification();
    NotificationManagerCompat.from(context).notify(0, notification);
}
}
```

Comment: please use **Data message** not **Notification Message** to receive data in `onMessageReceived()`, please refer this [Data Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages)

Comment: I use Data message. The only thing I need is don't show firebase push notification

Answer (score 0):

You should really use Data notifications from the server. Normal message notifications can't achieve this behaviour you're looking for. Check out the docs here:https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

So your request to Firebase from the server should look something like this:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "data":{
      "Nick" : "Mario",
      "body" : "great match!",
      "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Instead of:

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How these changes will help me in NOT showing firebase notification and showing only mine? Or onMessageReceived() from FirebaseMessagingService will start to call in this case when application is in background? The thing is onMessageReceived() doesn't call now when application is in background. So firebase push it's notification inspite of my willing

Comment: Because the behaviour is different between message and data typed notifications. Message typed notifications are idd handled by the Android system tray in some cases